# The Loss can’t back propagate to model’s parameters with my customized loss function

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function

I designed a customized loss:

```
class CustomIndicesEdgeAccuracyLoss(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes: int, selected_indices: list):
        super(CustomIndicesEdgeAccuracyLoss, self).__init__()
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.selected_indices = selected_indices

    def forward(self, input: torch.Tensor, target: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        batch_size, num_classes, feature_size = input.shape
        selected_input = input[::, ::, self.selected_indices]
        selected_target = target[::, self.selected_indices]
        selected_preds = torch.argmax(selected_input, dim=1)
        edge_acc = torch.eq(selected_preds, selected_target).sum()/torch.numel(selected_preds)
        loss = 1 – edge_acc
        loss.requires_grad = True

        return loss
```

But the `loss` won’t back propagate to model’s parameters, in other word, the gradient of model’s parameters are always 0 and the model’s parameters can’t be updated.
What’s possible reasons? How should I revise the codes?

Here is some information of the local variables of `forward()`:

```
input.shape: torch.Size([64, 3, 5])
target.shape:torch.Size([64, 5])
selected_input.shape: torch.Size([64, 3, 2]) 
selected_target.shape:torch.Size([64, 2])
```

PS. I ask the same question in [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/the-loss-cant-back-propagate-to-models-parameters-with-my-customized-loss-function/192393), so I will copy the answer from this post to there, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use accuracy as a loss function as it is non-differentiable. There is no gradient propagation through `torch.argmax`. You need to use a differentiable loss function.